# Number of repositories for GitHub Organization

Tags: github, open-source

How do I find the number of repos an organization has on GitHub?

If I click on each language it will tell me the number of repos with that language, but how do I get the total number of repos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use github search from : https://github.com/search with a filter like `org:my_organization` (also working with `user` filter) :

[An example](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=org%3Agoogle&ref=simplesearch) with google organization :

[image]

Note that if you want to include forked repository add `fork:true` :

[image]